# Google SERP returns the german version of our website instead of english

Tags: google-search-console, search-results

We have recently translated our website in many languages. Each language is displayed on a separate subdomain:

- https://de.example.com for German,
- https://fr.example.com for French
- etc...

if no subdomain is specified (naked domain or www), we display the English version unless there is a cookie specifying the language (that is set when a subdomain is visited). However Google always displays the German version of our page title and meta description. But the link is still www.example.com.

How do I force Google to display the english version on www and naked domain and in xxx language in xx.example.com?

Comment: Are you doing some kind of redirect??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hreflang for language and regional URLs

like this one

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://es.example.com/" />
```